# wget return Error 404 for an existing page

Tags: wget

I have some php files in the same directory. I can `wget` some of them but these two files. `wget` returs error 404 not found. I tried `--header` & `-referer` option but still doesn't work. Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permissions. Maybe the are not readable to the server.

Comment: It's 644 and all my files is using that permission.

Comment: And the owner is the same for all files?

Comment: Yes, the owner is the same which is root.